# Columns For Review Section Of Product Description

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Trying to split the review section of my Product Description into 2 columns. It is nested just below the Product Description. The actual reviews in one column and the Add Review form in another column along side it.

Site is Wordpress with Woocommerce. To date I have moved the Reviews out of the Tabs and just below the Product Description. Look here https://www.boatpartsforless.com/shop/marpac-fuelwater-separator-filter-7-0860/. So that the page is not so long and I feel looks better in the Reviews I would like to display as mentioned above in Columns.

I came across the code for creating columns php

```
<?php
function my_multi_col($content) {

$columns = explode('<h2>', $content);
$i = 0;

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    if (($i % 2) == 0) {
        $return .= '<div class="content_left">'."\n";
        if ($i > 1) {
            $return .= "<h2>";
        } else {
            $return .= '<div class="content_right">'."\n <h2>";
        }
        $return .= $column;
        $return .= '</p></div>';
        $i++;
    }
    if(isset($columns[1])) {
            $content = wpautop($return);
    } else {
            $content = wpautop($content);
    }
    echo $content;
}
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_multi_col');
?>
```

I believe adding it to the single-product-reviews.php file will do the trick, just can't figure out what to replace the h2's with.

Or, a way that makes sense if I am completely off base here.

Any push in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was making it way to difficult. Did it with CSS in Style Sheet.

```
/* Reviews In Columns */

#reviews #comments ol.commentlist {
float: right !important;
width: 60% !important;
}

#reviews #review_form_wrapper {
margin-top: 0 !important;
float: left !important;
}
```